# SQL Recursive query for look through

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table funds on a postgres database that contains the columns : Funds,  position, amount, Security Type, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundSahres.

The goal is to have a recursive sql query to understand what is contained in the funds, knowing that a ponderation needs to be done on each level.

To better explain the logic behind this, I have this sample table :

```
create table funds (Fund varchar(100), Position varchar(100),SecurityType varchar(100), Amount float, Price Float, TotalPositionValue Float, NumberOfFundShare Float);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 1', 'Apple', 'Stock', 78, 13, 1014, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 1', 'Fund 2', 'Fund', 10, 42, 424, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 1', 'Tesla', 'Stock', 85, 12, 1020, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 2', 'Amazon', 'Stock', 55, 44, 2423, 200);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 2', 'Meta', 'Stock', 64, 75, 4800, 200);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 2', 'Fund 3', 'Fund', 35, 36, 1262, 200);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 3', 'Microsoft', 'Stock', 75, 23, 1725, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 3', 'Apple', 'Stock', 34, 54, 1836, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 3', 'Fund 4', 'Fund', 91, 0, 44, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 4', 'Fund 5', 'Fund', 81, 2, 146, 300);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 5', 'Fund 6', 'Fund', 81, 4, 361, 200);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 6', 'Fund 7', 'Fund', 55, 8, 446, 100);
        insert into funds (Fund, Position, SecurityType, Amount, Price, TotalPositionValue, NumberOfFundShare) values ('Fund 7', 'Alphabet', 'Stock', 69, 47, 3243, 400);
```

[image]

So the Logic of the query goes like this : 2 parameters needs to be specified, **Fund Name** and **level** of view.

Let's take Fund 1 as an example, it contains Apple and Tesla as direct Stock and Fund 2 as a Fund.

The first level of the view would only give a filtering on Fund1.

The second level of the view would replace Fund 2 by it's pondered positions, the pondered positions are calculated like this : Amount of Fund 2 in Fund 1 divided by Number of Fund Shares of Fund 2 := 10/200 = 0.05, this value would be multiplied by the Amount and Total Position Value contained in the positions of Fund 2.

[image]

In this view we'd still have a Fund3 as a position, so we can further go to level3 and so on.

i am a little bit familiar with recursive CTE, but the step of ponderations seems off to me.

I have came with this query :

```
WITH RECURSIVE funds_tree AS(
    SELECT 
        0 AS level,
        f1.fund,
        f1.position,
        f1.SecurityType,
        f1.Amount,
        f1.Price,
        f1.TotalPositionValue,
        f1.NumberOfFundShare
    FROM funds f1
    WHERE f1.fund = 'Fund 1'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        level + 1,
        f2.fund,
        f2.position,
        f2.securityType,
        f2.amount,
        f2.price,
        f2.TotalPositionValue,
        f2.NumberOfFundShare
    FROM funds f2
    JOIN funds_tree ft ON ft.position = f2.fund
)
SELECT * FROM funds_tree;
```

But it still lacks the ponderation part, and i don't know if it's good performance wise to have all the level from the getgo.

Comment: `f2.amount` should be replaced with `f2.amount * ft.amount/f2.NumberOfFundShare` - a ratio of partitipation in the fund multiplied by the item value in the included fund. The same for `f2.TotalPositionValue`. Column `NumberOfFundShare` seems to be irrelevant because it contains denormalized information about fund which has no meaning when propagated to every parent row

Comment: Thank you for your answer @astentx :)
Do you think it's a good idea to have all the levels computed on a single query for future scalability purposes ? If say that during runtime the level 3 is the most requested level, making the generated view go through all the levels would introduce an unecessary overhead no ?
I was also thinking about using two tables funds and funds position with a one to many relationship leading to use a join to generate the views, but would it be useful ?
The recursive query gives an elegant solution, but I was thinking if it was the most optimized one too.

Comment: I think you may use a parameterized function to limit the depth of the tree, so you'll be able to avoid extra processing when it is not required. Here's an example: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/4k5uiVko). What about storage: it's more about the data model and it's hard to tell what would be a good tradeoff between consistency and performance. Of course a single table is better than join, but it may lead to inconsistent data that would be hard to repair.